# Can there be a moment at a hinge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics

I've recently started studying statics and I was told that a ***hinge cannot offer moment reaction***. It offers only reaction forces in x and y directions:

[image]

But when doing problems I've just encountered a problem shown below where the hinge offers moment reaction. At point $A$ we have an hinge. It shouldn't provide any moment reaction. But it feels there will be a moment at $A$. The $500N$ force tries to rotate the beam clockwise and $A$ seems to resist it. What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: As always it is important to recognize that certain "facts" are dependant on the domian. Real, physical hinges (and even bearings) can provide moments in the form of friction, but ... (A) These are typically small in built to purpose devices and are idealized as zero. (B) When the subjects is *statics* in particular any frictional momement that may exist when a configuration is established can be exprect to be transient (thought he time scale for creep can be longer than that for most transients).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At point $A$ we have an hinge. It shouldn't provide any moment
>   reaction. But it feels there will be a moment at $A$.

The hinge A is not providing a "moment reaction". A support provides a moment reaction when it prevents rotation about the support. That's what you have for the cantilever support (first drawing in top picture). The vertical reaction of hinge A is preventing rotation about the point of application of 500 N load. It does not prevent rotation about A.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh the hinge $A$ is preventing the rotation about the *rightmost* point! I see now... Thank you so much:)